# Proof that $x^2-98xy+y^2=0, \, x\ne y$ has no soultions over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The problem is to prove that
$$x^2-98xy+y^2=0, \, x\ne y$$
has no solutions over integers. I figured out that this equation has a solution over integers if and only if
$$x^2-10xy+y^2=0, \, x\ne y$$
has a solution over integers, but don't know what to do next. Could anyone help me with this problem?

**Edit:** The reduction of the middle term can be made only when we assume an additional condition, namely $x\ne -y$.

Comment: How do you show that the second equation has an integer solution if and only if the first does?

Comment: Reducing the middle term is a quick procedure. Provided that $x\ne y$ (and $x\ne −y,$ I should have mentioned this in the question, this condition should be present when we want to make the reduction), we can make the substitution $x=a^2$ and $y=b^2$ to get $a^4−98a^2b^2+b^4=0$, which can be regrouped to $100a^2b^2=a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4=(a^2+b^2)^2$, after taking the square root and regrouping we get $a^2−10ab+b^2=0\implies (x^2-98xy+y^2=0\iff x^2−10xy+y^2=0, x\ne y, x\ne -y, x\in \mathbb Z, y\in \mathbb Z).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(x, y) \in \Bbb Z^2$ is a solution of
$$ \tag{*}
x^2 -98xy + y^2 = 0$$
 if and only if $u = \frac xy$ is a *rational* solution of
$$ \tag{**}
 u^2 - 98 u + 1 = 0 \, .
$$
The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) states that the only possible rational roots of $(**)$ are $u= 1$ and $u = -1$, but those are not solutions. Therefore $(*)$ has no solution in the integers.

Alternatively you can mimic the proof of the rational root theorem and show that if $(x, y) \in \Bbb Z^2$ is a solution of  $(*)$ with *coprime* integers $x,y$ then
$$
 y (98 x -y ) = x^2
$$
implies that $y$ divides $x$. Similarly, $x$ divides $y$, so that $x = \pm y$, which again gives a contradiction.

Comment: ($+1$) Much more direct than my solution

Comment: Already, if $y(98x-y)=x^2$ and $x,y$ are co-prime, we know that $y$ must equal $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quadratic in $y$ with solutions
$$y=(49\pm20\sqrt{6})x$$
but for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have that
$$y=(49\pm20\sqrt{6})x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$$
as $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational. If there was a solution then
$$\sqrt{6}=\pm\frac{y-49x}{20x}\in\mathbb{Q}$$
which contradicts the fact that $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to prove it using divisibility theory.

Let us assume $(x,y)$, where $x \neq y$, is an integer solution of the given equation. First of all, if at least one of $x$ and $y$ is zero, then the other is zero as well. So, we can assume $x,y \neq 0$.

Now, we rewrite the given equation as $(x-y)^2 = 96xy$. Since $3 \mid 96$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
& 3 \mid (x-y)^2 \\
\implies & 3 \mid (x-y) \\
\implies & 9 \mid (x-y)^2 \\
\implies & 9 \mid 96xy \\
\implies & 3 \mid xy \\
\end{align}
$$

So, $3 \mid x$ or $3 \mid y$. If $3 \mid x$ , then $3 \mid y$ because $3 \mid (x-y)$. Similarly, $3 \mid y$ will lead us to $3 \mid x$. It is now established that $3 \mid x$ and $3 \mid y$.

Let $p,q,k \gt 0$ be largest integers such that $3^p \mid x$ , $3^q \mid y$ , and $3^k \mid (x-y)$. Note that $p$, $q$, and $k$ are finite because none of $x$, $y$, and $x-y$ is zero. Then, $2k$ is the largest integer such that $3^{2k} \mid (x-y)^2$ and $p+q+1$ is the largest integer such that $3^{p+q+1} \mid 96xy$.

We must have that $2k = p+q+1$. Since $2k-1$ is odd, $p$ and $q$ have different parity, and hence can't be equal. WLOG we can assume that $p \lt q$. It is easy to see that $3^p$ is the largest power of three that divides $x-y$. Therefore $k=p$, and we get $p=q+1 \gt q$, which clearly is a contradiction.